# Webrequest and webresponse, how do I get the respond?

Tags: c#

Im trying to use webrequest and webresponse in order to post an image to `http://uploads.im/` and get an answer back containing the href to the image.

The API (`http://uploads.im/apidocs`) describes it like this:

```
The simplest example of a call. Copy this URL and open in your browser.
http://uploads.im/api?upload=http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo66.png
```

Sure enough, it works. You get redirected to a page containing the href among other info.
I try to recreate this in my MVC-project like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
{              
       WebRequest wrq = WebRequest.Create("http://uploads.im/api?upload=http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo66.png");                    
       WebResponse wrs = wrq.GetResponse();
}
```

Hoping that the `wrs` would contain the same info as the page in the example...of course it does not..What am i missing here?

EDIT: This is what I get back:

[image]

Comment: 1 min and I post an image of the result

Comment: Did you try Googling your exact question title, or just reading the documentation for the classes you're using, to see how to read the response?

Comment: Sorry..cant say I did read much documentation for the classes. I´ll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be reading the response:

```
public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
{
    WebRequest wrq = WebRequest.Create("http://uploads.im/api?upload=http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo66.png");

    using (WebResponse wrs = wrq.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = wrs.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Here the json variable will contain
        // the response from the server. You could
        // parse it with a JSON parser such as JSON.NET
        // and extract the information you are looking for
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, im gonna try to learn about the parser now and see if I cant read the result! Thanks!